# How to resolve memory leak in node.js due to .map function

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I am trying to export 9 million records from my mssql database to a mysql database using a node.js app

I am running into a memory issue which I suspect is due to my map functions.( Bluebird Promise.map)

The below Myfucntion() calls the doThis() function which gets a set of records from my Mssql database then insert the record into a MySql database.

```
Myfucntion(){
Promise.map(ids, id => doThis(id).then(results => console.log(results)), { concurrency: 5});
}

const doThis = async (id) => {
  try{
       const results = await sql.query`select results where id = ${id}`;
        if((results && results.recordset) && results.recordset.length > 0 ) {
          results.recordset.map(asset =>  insertResultslAsset(convertResultAsset(asset)));
        }
  }
  catch(err){
      console.log(err)
  }
 };
```

The convertResultAsset(asset) function creates a 4 properties object before doing the inserts.

I suspect the  memory leakage occurs because the converted assets are being stored incrementally in memory with the .map iterations

I  was able to  alleviated the problem by running --max-old-space-size=20000 on the program.

After I perform the inserts from the doThis() function there is no need for me to store the converted Assets.

Is there a way to release these objects from the .map function?

Comment: my 50 cent: when dealing with 9M records your code should be optimized for performance more than for friendlyness. I think you're kinda better of using classic for loops and also... what's the deal with getting a bunch of ids and then querying for those? Isnt there another way? Are those 9 millon queries you're trying to perform? Is this code a run-once script for a conversion or it will run periodically?

Comment: The `insertResultslAsset` or `convertResultAsset` implementations could be leaky.

Answer (score 1):

Too much `async` and `promises` in one chunk of code. Also, bluebird has internal error handler hook, so it is not necessary to use `try-catch` block (<del>probably, this block could decrease performance, see this article: [optimization-killers](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#2-unsupported-syntax)</del>)

This is the first simplified version:

```js
const debug = require('debug')('my-app-name')

Myfucntion(){
    return Promise.map(
        ids,
        id => doThis(id),
        { concurrency: 5}
    )

}

function doThis(id) {
    const results = sql.query('select results where id = ${id}');
    if (
        results &&
        results.recordset &&
        results.recordset.length > 0
    ) {
        return results
            .recordset
            .map(asset => insertResultslAsset(convertResultAsset(asset)))
            .then(res => debug(res))
            .catch(err => debug('error', err);
    }
    return null
}
```

I have removed the `console.log`, bcz I am not sure about its async/sync nature, `debug` module, probably, works better in most cases (but to see its output you should run program with environment flags, like this: `DEBUG=* nodejs app.js`)

And I am not sure for 100% that problem is solved, because two unknown functions are still there:

- `insertResultslAsset`
- `convertResultAsset`

May be these functions contain closures, and unnecessary lock variables?

Comment: that's very simplified!

Comment: @user5328504, sorry, I've sent without code. Probably `Ctrl+Enter` was pressed to early)))

Comment: This helped. I fololowed exactly as you said .My memory is very stable now. Still cant figure out what exactly was the culprit.

Comment: Actually this if i remove .then(res => debug(res))
        .catch(err => debug('error', err)) the memory goes back up

Comment: @user1526912, probably, it was caused by extra async/await . Also we could explicitly drop unused returned results.. or... I am not sure what exactly, lets call debug-experts))